# Confusion with respect to monotonicity of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

In the accepted answer in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549767/lim-sup-and-lim-infs-of-brownian-motion-b-t-sqrtt-as-t-to-infty-or-as) it is claimed that Brownian motions have the property that $$\sup\limits_{s \leq t} \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{s}} \leq \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}}$$

Can someone help me understand why is this true? I assume this really means that for any $C \in \mathbb{R}$, $s \in (0,t]$: $$P\bigg(\frac{B_s}{\sqrt{s}} < C \bigg) \leq P\bigg(\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}} < C \bigg)$$

If true then this would be analogous to prove that for all $C,s$ as before:

$$1 \leq \sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{C\sqrt{t}}e^{x^2/2t}dx}{\int_{-\infty}^{C\sqrt{s}}e^{y^2/2t}dy}$$

But again, why does this inequality hold?

Comment: I did not find this claim in the linked answer, could you be more specific?

Comment: @Sarah. The post claims $\sup\limits_{s \leq t} \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{s}} \color{red}{\geq} \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}}$ which is trivial and trivially leads to the statement about the probabilities. But that means $P(\color{red}{\sup\limits_{s \leq t}} \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{s}}\leq C)\leq P(\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}}\leq C)$.

Comment: Ok @KurtG. pretty simple indeed! You can post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kurt mentioned in his comment, the inequality should be flipped:
$$\sup_{s \leq t} \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{s}} \geq \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}}$$
where this inequality follows since the supremum is taken over a set which includes $\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}}$.

There is, however, a misreading of the linked post, which says that "$\sup_{s \leq t} \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{s}}$ is monotonic with respect to $t$". This means that if you define the process $M_t = \sup_{s \leq t} \frac{B_s}{\sqrt{s}}$, then the process is non-decreasing; that is , for $r \leq t$ we have $M_r \leq M_t$. Again, this follows as for $t$ the supremum is taken over a larger set.